# How do you parse a sentence like this?

Tags: traducción

> Yo te las pienso buscar cuando tenga suficiente tiempo.

I'm having trouble replacing the direct object pronoun (las) and indirect object pronoun (te) with their corresponding nouns. It's also unclear what the translation of `pensar + infinitive` and `tenga` is in this context. Here's what I've gotten:

> "I think of searching for you [te] when there's enough time for them [las]"

This doesn't sound right to me. How would I go about analyzing a sentence like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's build this translation starting with a slightly simpler sentence:

```
Yo las buscaré cuando tenga suficiente tiempo
    |     |
    |     |
    +-----O-------+
          |       |
          |       |
I will look for them when I have enough time.
```

Now, with your original sentence:

```
Yo te las pienso buscar cuando tenga suficiente tiempo.
    |  |     |
    |  |     |
    +--------------------------+
       |     |                 |
    +--------+                 |
    |  |                       |
    |  +-----------------+     |
    |                    |     |
    |                    |     |
I intend to search for them for you when I have enough time.
```

That `pienso buscar` means that the speaker has an intention to do the searching, and I think it is expressed better with `to intend`. I also think that `look for` could be used instead of `search`, but in the case of the last translation it may produce a mess with `for you`.

Another option to express the same idea of the original sentence in Spanish could be:

> Tengo la intención de buscártelas cuando tenga suficiente tiempo.

---

**Español:**

Ese `pienso buscar` da la idea de intención, que creo que es mejor expresable en inglés con `to intend`. También creo que se puede usar `look for` en vez de `search`, pero en el caso de la última traducción puede que se enrede con el `for you`.

Otra manera de expresar esa idea en español es:

> Tengo la intención de buscártelas cuando tenga suficiente tiempo.

Comment: Thank you. Also why is `tenga` used instead of `tengo`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 because that hasn't happened yet chronologically speaking (and, theoretically, may not ever happen)

Comment: @0x499602D2: `tenga` is subjunctive mood.

Comment: @0x499602D2 *When* often triggers the subjuntive mood, not always, of course. Compare: *cuando tengo tiempo* (I do have the time); *cuando tenga tiempo* (I don't have the time, yet)